# Bad read performance on Spark over HBase Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

When reading 161 000 elements from HBase (462 MB based on HDFS file size) Spark spends at least **6 seconds** to read them.

HBase is configured to use a block cache. During the test (there is no other process running at that moment), the block cache has a size of 470.1 MB (752.0 MB free).

- All the elements are in the block cache.
- The executor is running in an Yarn container (yarn mode) of 1408 MB memory.
- Everything is running on a single node (including the master) over an Amazon m4 large node.
- There is no other row in the table and a range scanning is performed.
- [RDD initialized like this](https://gist.github.com/sebge2emasphere/0fbac847fb7141b22bced4114792a116)
- [Executor Logs](https://gist.github.com/sebge2emasphere/01d2759365288ddbd0a085d23e09e6c9) (it took 8 seconds in debug logging level)
- The job is executed via Spark JobServer
- Even a simple count on the RDD (no other operation) takes 5 seconds

I don't know what I can do based on the figures below. Where does the executor spend its time? How can I identify the bottleneck?

Thank you very much,
Sébastien.

[image: Job stage details]

Comment: timings in logs (stdout/stderr) don't help?

Comment: there is no warning in sparrk jobserver, neither in the log of the spark AM. There is no log associated to the spark executor.

Comment: I succeed to get more logs (I put them in the attachments). Thanks :)